# Launcher Name Of Installed Apps

Tags: android, launcher

I have to get list of installed apps from android device . I am able to get the list. But there is some problem in getting the **launcher name** (which is defined in launcher activity tag in manifest not in application tag) of applications from the PackageInfo object. How to get the launcher name of installed apps from the PackageInfo object.??

I have tried in this way

```
packageInfo.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)
```

But this is not giving launcher name. It is giving the application tag string.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code to get the launcher activity of all packages:

```
   class PInfo {
    private String appname = "";
    private String pname = "";
    private String versionName = "";
    private int versionCode = 0;
    private Drawable icon;
    private void prettyPrint() {
        Log.v(appname + "\t" + pname + "\t" + versionName + "\t" + versionCode);
    }
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getPackages() {
    ArrayList<PInfo> apps = getInstalledApps(false); /* false = no system packages */
    final int max = apps.size();
    for (int i=0; i<max; i++) {
        apps.get(i).prettyPrint();
    }
    return apps;
}

private ArrayList<PInfo> getInstalledApps(boolean getSysPackages) {
    ArrayList<PInfo> res = new ArrayList<PInfo>();        
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for(int i=0;i<packs.size();i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((!getSysPackages) && (p.versionName == null)) {
            continue ;
        }
        PInfo newInfo = new PInfo();
        newInfo.appname = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
        newInfo.pname = p.packageName;
        newInfo.versionName = p.versionName;
        newInfo.versionCode = p.versionCode;
        newInfo.icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
        res.add(newInfo);
    }
    return res; 
}
```

Comment: I am getting the list with
List<PackageInfo> allPackagesList = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

Comment: I want to get the Application name from the PackageInfo object

Comment: I am able to get the list of applications.But my problem is to get the launcher name of application from PackageInfo object.

Comment: Your answer gives the package name for Activity.Not the Launcher name of application.

Comment: The method you used in updated answer is 
 CharSequence getApplicationLabel (ApplicationInfo info) 
Requires an ApplicationInfo object.

Comment: The label defined as android:label in Launcher Activity of the Application.

Comment: The label defined as android:label in Launcher Activity of the Application.

Comment: p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString()
It doesnot give the android:label tag value defined in Launcher activity of the Application.
It gives the android : tag value defined in application tag of manifest.
I want android:label for launcher activity of Application(Because this is the value displayed in Application area )

Answer (score 0):

If you want the applications that handle the launcher, then you can look for applications that handle the intent filter Intent.CATEGORY_HOME with the PackageManager.

Comment: I am able to get the list of applications.But my problem is to get the launcher name of application from PackageInfo object.